# PropertyChangedEventArgs wpf Windows 8

Tags: wpf

I have an wpf app that works fine in Windows 7. It fails in Windows 8. Basically a line has a start and an end location. This can either be edited by dragging the line or by changing coordinates in a grid.

If the line is dragged the grid should update. I use an observable collection and t is a item in the collection.

This worked in Win 7 -

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
t.taskendlocation = 100;
PropertyChanged(t, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Taskendlocation"));
```

but fails in Win 8 with the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably null because nothing has attached to the PropertyChanged event yet. You should always be doing a null check before calling the event.

```
t.taskendlocation = 100;
NotifyPropertyChanged("taskendlocation");



public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
{
   If (PropertyChanged != null)
   {
       PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had thought the same and added the code as you have done. Property changed returns null so skips the code in Win 8. In Win 7 it does have a value and gets processed. It must be Win 8 changing something?

Comment: Is it the same app your running on both OS?

Comment: Yes absolutely. In Visual Studio and also when installed as an app. I do the same edit as well. It appears something has changed in Win 8.

Comment: Its not a windows8 thing as I have plenty of app running in win8 with INotifyPropertyChanged events, I'm guessing your app is compiled in .NET4 so perhaps your Win8 machine does not have all the .NET4 installed as win8 is now .NET4.5

Comment: I thought .Net 4.5 included .Net 4.0? I can't install .net 4.0 on windows 7. Maybe VS 2010 isn't going to cut it on Win 8 as it doesn't support 4.5

Comment: It was just a guess, as I have no trouble with VS2010 creating WPF apps for Win8, seems a bit odd, I could not find anything on google about people having this issue, very strange.